# Git and I can't merge due to a conflict

Tags: git

I can't get out if this mess. I can't get back into dev...and I just want to forget about master and merge all of dev into master.

```
git merge --no-ff development 
Auto-merging servers/bidder_server.py
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in servers/bidder_server.py
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I don't care about master now. I just want to get all of dev in master. How to I wipe clean master?

Comment: "I dont care about master" #FiveWordTechHorrors

Comment: Are you using the repo exclusively?

Comment: Then go to the master and reset your master branch hard to the dev branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I believe you need to complete the merge in whatever way you can.  Don't worry about leaving garbage files, just finish the merge.

Then you can take a look at your commit history by either looking at `git log` or `git reflog` and finding an appropriate commit to revert to.  I would recommend creating a new branch to use as your temporary staging area.

In order to revert, just use `git reset --hard <commit>`.  If what you see in your branch looks acceptable to use in master, use the same command after switching to master.  Then, finally, you can merge dev into master.

Comment: Not workinhg git reset --hard
HEAD is now at c796a13 t

Comment: git commit -m 't'
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Comment: git merge --no-ff development 
Auto-merging servers/bidder_server.py
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in servers/bidder_server.py
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Comment: @Tampa: how about reading something about how to resolve conflicts in git?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore changes from `master` without discarding them completely, you could use [the `ours` merge strategy](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html).

> This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches. Note that this is different from the -Xours option to the recursive merge strategy.

To use it, merge `master` into `development` to create the merge commit with the resulting tree matching `development`.

```
git checkout development
git merge -s ours master
```

Then, merge back to `master` so both branches refer to the merge commit.

```
git checkout master
git merge development
```